# PhpStorm TypeScript code style

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, code-formatting, jetbrains-ide

A question is a bit weird but it pretty annoys me.
The existing code formatting for decorators is like this:

```
@Component({
               selector:    'app-service',
               templateUrl: './service.component.html',
               styleUrls:   ['./service.component.css'],
               host:        {
                   class: "row"
               }
           })
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
@Component({
   selector:    'app-service',
   templateUrl: './service.component.html',
   styleUrls:   ['./service.component.css'],
   host:        {
       class: "row"
   }
})
```

(like in a class or function declaration)

I've searched in IDE settings multiple times, I can't find it! Is this config missed in settings or I am bad searcher?

Comment: *"Is this config missed in settings or I am bad searcher?"* Most likely the 2nd one -- such obvious setting will not be missed (works for me).. unless there is a glitch. Please show your setting for TypeScript -- `Wrapping & Braces` tab. But before that -- please try resetting to using "Default" schema first.

Comment: @LazyOne God.. Resetting saved my life, thanks! If you place it as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I will. But still -- please post a screenshot of your Code Style if you still have that your custom schema saved (that once activated does not work as you wish).